# Mouse Move fires Mouse Click (Adobe Air)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air

I am trying to have two guestures on a SpriteVisualElement which I thought should be pretty simple implemented:

Mouse_Move for sweep Gestures and mouse click to enable..

So I have 2 Eventlisteners on my stage:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, taphandler);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mousedownhandler);
```

The main problem is that every type of sweeping on the screen also fires the taphandler()..

Any ideas on how to identify the correct event?

I tried to to my taphandler only if(!event.buttondown) but no success.

Comment: Flex has separate touch gesture events, use them

Comment: Gesture events just bring me "simple" swipe recognition.. I need to use every position during a swipe gesture which I only get with TouchEvent or MouseEvent.. but both collide with click

Comment: looks like you're going to have to take the mousedown event as touch start and mouseup as touch end. Then you'll have to write code to check if the mousedown and up occur within a certain interval (click), for a longer interval (hold) or the location is moving (drag)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to handle MouseEvent.CLICK specifically? Or are you just trying to handle a tap and a drag separately.  If this is the case, try one of these two for a tap:

```
MySprite.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, taphandler);
MySprite.addEventListener(PressAndTapGestureEvent.GESTURE_PRESS_AND_TAP, taphandler);
```

(note that these event handlers are on your sprite, and not the stage)

For touch and drag, try:

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

MySprite.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, onTouchBegin);
MySprite.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, onTouchMove);
MySprite.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, onTouchEnd);

function onTouchBegin(eBegin:TouchEvent) {
     eBegin.target.startTouchDrag(eBegin.touchPointID, false, bg.getRect(this));
     trace("touch begin");

 }

function onTouchMove(eMove:TouchEvent) {
    trace(eMove.stageX);
}

function onTouchEnd(eEnd:TouchEvent) {
     eEnd.target.stopTouchDrag(eEnd.touchPointID);
     trace("touch end");
}
```

The only issue you may run into is that TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP and TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN both might be interpreted as MouseClick.TOUCH on your device, so if you have a handler attached to your sprite for MouseClick.TOUCH, you will have a conflict.

BTW, most of this info is from the [Adobe Actionscript 3.0 Reference - TouchEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/TouchEvent.html)

Comment: Hi eterps, nice code but nothing for my problem.. It even is not necessary to use a multitouch, transformgesture or any other than mouse event because the tap/click is always firing also while moving.. I got it now by assuming that every event is tap, but checking if its even more and prevent the tap when there is moving on the screen.